# Mac OS and possibly other GUIs: Why is default "s-g" behaving differently from "C-s" in isearch-mode

Tags: key-bindings, isearch, gui, mac

I don't really want **<kbd>s-g</kbd>** to exit the Isearch minor mode but it does. The reason this is happening to me is unclear, because investigation of the binding of **<kbd>s-g</kbd>** reveals it is supposed to be a standard `isearch-repeat-forward`. So it seems that Emacs has gotten into a state where two keys bound to the same thing have different behavior.

Question: Why is Emacs behaving this way, how is it happening, and is this intended behavior?

1. Edit contents of /tmp/blah.txt to be:

```
something
something
```

2. emacs -Q /tmp/blah.txt
3. **<kbd>s-f</kbd>something** -- modeline should now indicate you are in Isearch minor mode
4. Enter **<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>s-g</kbd>** -- note that output indicates both s-g and C-s are bound to this function (*isearch-repeat-forward*)

```
s-g runs the command isearch-repeat-forward (found in global-map),
which is an interactive compiled Lisp function in ‘isearch.el’.

It is bound to C-s, C-M-s, <menu-bar> <search-menu>
<isearch-repeat-forward>, s-g.
```

4. Press one of

   - **<kbd>s-g</kbd>** -- modeline indicates Isearch minor mode is no longer active
   - **<kbd>C-s</kbd>** -- modeline indicates Isearch minor mode is still active
5. Start over and press the key you didn't press in step 4

My Emacs About panel indicates `Version 28.0.50 (9.0)`.

Comment: Be aware that Emacs 28 development snapshots reflect ongoing changes. In particular, there are changes afoot to make Isearch use the minibuffer, and that could perhaps be a cause of the problem you're seeing. You might try with an Emacs release (e.g. 27.2) instead, to see if the problem is there as well. If not, consider filing a bug or otherwise reporting it: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: In addition to what @Drew said, I recommend avoiding key chords that end up bound to ⌘ (a la super, by default) when you can. macOS isn't always great at passing the key events down to the application. In this case, `isearch`, use the chords with Control and Meta instead. Rebind your Caps Lock to Control if you have to.